# Python scripts link to GUI using an IDE

Tags: python, gui, scripting

I am studying python. Now I can write python scripts(codes) to some extent.
I am interested in making GUI to those written programs.I like to do it using an IDE rather than using PyGTK or Tkinter.
Can anyone help me how to start with this and link my scripts to a GUI.
I downloaded a IDE called "glade". But I don't know how to use this IDE.
I need some tutorial guide also. Can anyone help me.Please.Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Glade is not an IDE it's a GUI builder/designer. Glade just helps you create the interface of your application, Coding comes later.

If you're not comfortable with PyGTK you should try [PySide](http://qt-project.org/wiki/PySide), the Python binding of Qt.

Comment: Thank you. Do you have any resource of tutorial for glade?

Comment: There are a lot of videos on Youtube.
However, I really don't recommend Glade or (Gtk in general) for you, Qt Designer is far more powerful and easier than Glade.
If you wish to try, this is a PySide tutorial : http://zetcode.com/gui/pysidetutorial/ and this is a Qt Designer tutorial : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LYF0spYkXUs

Comment: Thank you very much. I will start with PySide.Thankz again.